# Laravel - How do I count an nested eager loaded relation query?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Relationship:
Category hasMany CategoryBoards
CategoryBoards hasMany threads
CategoryBoards hasMany threadPosts THROUGH threads

I want something like this but it doesn't work.

```
$returnData['categories'] = CategoryView::with('categoryBoards')
   ->withCount([
   'categoryBoards.threads AS threadCount',
   'categoryBoards.threadPosts AS threadPostCount'
   ])->get();
```

This one **works** so I think my relationship is OK now, but I only need the COUNT of thread and posts, not objects.

```
$returnData['categories'] = CategoryView::with(['categoryBoards.threads', 'categoryBoards.threadPosts'])->get();
```

Comment: follow this https://softonsofa.com/tweaking-eloquent-relations-how-to-get-hasmany-relation-count-efficiently/

Comment: That's so old. What he did can be achieved with withCount. Mine is I need to count a nested eager loading relation.

Comment: Are you still looking for a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try

```
CategoryView::with(['categoryBoards' => function($q){
$q->count('*');
}])->get()
```

You can do anything if you give array with key -> relation name and value callback.

Comment: It doesn't work. I want to count threads and thread posts, not categoryboards,